# how to solve Error: expected: /br read: div?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am doing XML parsing using this code:

```
public void getfile(String url) {
    try{
        String URL = url;
        ALL_URL = new ArrayList<String>();
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

        Log.i("URLis: ", url);

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            Log.i("valueis " , e.getAttribute("src").trim());
            String value = base + e.getAttribute("src").trim();
            ALL_URL.add(value);         
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) { }
}
```

It used to work, but I don't know what happened.

The LogCat:

```
01-10 13:01:30.206: E/Error:(8632): expected: /br read: div (position:END_TAG </div>@13:7 in java.io.StringReader@44ededa0)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your xml file, the file is not well-formed. It contains an unbalanced `<br>` tag inside a `<div>`. The parser detects this error when it sees the end of the `<div>`.